# cakephp see the compiled SQL Query before execution

Tags: sql, debugging, logging, cakephp-1.3

My query gets the timeout error on each run. Its a pagination with joins.
I want to debug the SQL, but since I get a timeout, I can't see it.

How can I see the compiled SQL Query before execution?

---

Some cake code:

```
$this -> paginate = array(
        'limit' => '16',
        'joins' => array( array(
                'table' => 'products',
                'alias' => 'Product',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('ProductModel.id = Product.product_model_id')
            )),
        'fields' => array(
            'COUNT(Product.product_model_id) as Counter',
            'ProductModel.name'
            ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'ProductModel.category_id' => $category_id,
        ),
        'group' => array('ProductModel.id')
    );
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First off, set the `debug` variable to 2 in `app/config/config.php`.

Then add:

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump');?>
```

at the end of your layout. This should actually be commented out in your default cake layout.

**You will now be able see all SQL queries that go to the database.**

Now copy the query and use the [SQL EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) command (link is for MySQL) over the database to see what the query does in the [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database). For more on CakePHP debugging check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html).

Since your script doesn't even render you can try to get the latest log directly from the datasource with:

```
function getLastQuery()
{
    $dbo = $this->getDatasource();
    $logs = $dbo->getLog();
    $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
    return $lastLog['query'];
}
```

This needs to be in a model since the `getDatasource()` function is defined in a model. 
Inspect the whole `$logs` variable and see what's in there.

Comment: thanks. but it's not working.  
the problem is that the script never get to the part of rendering, since theh time out is in the controller-action level.

Comment: And, this script will return the last query from the previous execution?

Comment: Not entirely sure since I do not remmember what the exact return is.
Just try it. It will for sure return the log of the last query.
Just dump the `$logs` variable and inspect it.

Comment: Use `ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')` to get datasource when invoking from controller

Answer (score 5):

One more thing you can do is ....

Go to Cake/Model/DataSource/DboSource.php and locate function execute() and print $sql variable. 
That should print the sql.

This certainly is not be the cleanest way (as you are changing Cake directory) .. but certainly would be quickest just to debug if something is not working with sql.

Comment: When everything else is totally broken because of a rogue query, this is sometimes the most helpful way!

Comment: The answer is also helpful for command-line environments where you don't have access to the `sql_dump` element.

Comment: Thanks! This one helped :)

Comment: Inspired from this answer, as of Cakephp 3.9 the path to paginator file is vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/Paginator.php in which $cleanQuery at line number 172 can be printed to quick view of query. I tried a few other ways but they did not work. queries log worked but I wanted it printed on the page.

Answer (score 3):

```
Try...
function getLastQuery($model) {
    $dbo = $model->getDatasource();
    $logData = $dbo->getLog();
    $getLog = end($logData['log']);
    echo $getLog['query'];
}
```

Comment: This function works well on a server with PHP 5.4.32 but not on a server with 5.5.16 on that case $dbo->getLog() is just empty. On the other server I get full logs. Anyone any idea why the function doesn't work on the 5.5. version?

Comment: @user1555112 I'm not sure what the problem is, but it works fine on 5.6.1

Comment: @user1555112 probably you had debug mode off in your config, if your using this->log or CakeLog

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to show all executed query of your given model:

```
  $sqllog = $this->ModelName->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);       
  debug($sqllog);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class YourController extends AppController {
    function testfunc(){
        $this->Model->find('all', $options);
        echo 'SQL: '.$this->getLastQuery();
    }

    function getLastQuery()
    {
        $dbo = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
        $logs = $dbo->getLog();
        $lastLog = end($logs['log']);
        return $lastLog['query'];
    }
}
```

or you can get all the query by adding following line in to the function execute() in lib/Cake/Model/DataSource.php

```
Debugger::dump($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

set the debug variable to 2 in app/config/config.php.

```
echo $this->Payment->save();
```

Out put like =>SQL Query: INSERT INTO `photoora_photoorange`.`payments` VALUES (*******)

[insert query][2]

Answer (score -1):

set the debug variable to 2 in app/config/config.php.

[image]

And
[image]