# Cakephp Find Convert to Sql Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Cakephp find data in controller also can with sql syntax,

example :

```
$this->Post->find('all');
```

in sql :

```
select * from posts
```

convert query to cakephp find syntax is available at http://dogmatic69.com/sql-to-cakephp-find-converter

but whether there is any link for me if I wanna convert my cakephp find to query..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Asking for a link is off-topic

Comment: @Rishi : you want to convert my find cakephp to query ?

Comment: @Breeze : I'm sorry for that, I need it if the link exists but Thanks for your advice..

Comment: @Onesinus check out our sister site for software recommendations, the question might be on-topic there: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just add the following line after your find query . 
pr($this->Post->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false));exit ;

Answer (score 1):

If I got what you are asking, here is the answer

> SQL calls that you can’t or don’t want to make via other model
>   methods can be made using the model’s query() method (though this
>   should only rarely be necessary).

`query()` uses the table name in the query as the array key for the returned data, rather than the model name. For example:

```
$this->POST->query("SELECT* from posts;");
```

Here is the link for cakephp [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)

Comment: yes you got my question, but I search link which can convert to query from my cakephp find..

Comment: @OnesinusSaut This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780482/cakephp-see-the-compiled-sql-query-before-execution) can help you out

Comment: Wait, I will try your suggestion page, If Answer my question i will confirm and correct your answer...