# cakephp belongsToMany with 4 tables

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, model-associations, cakephp-3.x

We have 4 tables

1. Users

   -id
2. Profiles

   -id

   -user_id
3. Questions

   -id
4. Options

   -id
5. ProfileQuestions

   -id

   -profile_id

   -question_id

   -option_id

Now i require to get all profiles and each profile have multiple questions and each question has many options.

User Model

```
    $this->hasMany('Profiles', [
      'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
```

Profiles Model

```
     $this->belongsToMany('Questions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'question_id',
        'joinTable' => 'profile_questions',
        'through' => 'ProfileQuestions'  ,
        'joinType' => 'LEFT']);
```

Questions Model

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Options', [
        'foreignKey' => ['question_id'],
        'targetForeignKey' => 'option_id',
        'joinTable' => 'profile_questions',
        'through' => 'ProfileQuestions'
    ]);
```

ProfileQuestions Model

```
     $this->belongsTo('Profile', [
        'foreignKey' => 'profile_id',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Questions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Options', [
        'foreignKey' => 'option_id'
    ]);
```

Controller code to get the result

```
     $query = $this->Users->find('first')
                $query->contain(['Profiles.Questions.Options']);
```

Error

```
    Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 408944640) (tried to allocate 665912212 bytes) in vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement.php on line 39
```

Issue is related to Associations. If we set the profile_id where condition with the options contain then it works for that profile id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Out of memory, but I do have plenty of memory (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015569/fatal-error-out-of-memory-but-i-do-have-plenty-of-memory-php)

Comment: This is related to some issue in association.

Comment: it might be helpful if you print and see the compiled SQL query https://stackoverflow.com/a/16808024/1464519

Comment: `This is related to some issue in association.` - It obviously is not, the error message tells you why. I bet on that you simply fetch to much data and the memory is filled up. Read your data in chunks, problem solved.